# Can I determine which employee is logged in?

Tags: quickbooks-online

I connect with QBO using oAuth per documentation (using PHP), and I can successfully pull back a list of all employees.  What I'd like to do, though, is determine which of the employees that are returned corresponds with the user that is logged in.  Anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

The QuickBooks API does not support this.